# PowerShell script to check the property of Who can view the membership of the Group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spgroup

Is there any powershell exists , wherein i can check the property of a SPGroup "who can view the membership of the group" in my site collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know, In Group Settings, the `Who can view the membership of the group` property can be set to

- Group Members.
- EveryOne.

[image]

by running the following cmdlets, you can get the corresponding value as `True` or `False` from this property `OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership`

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://Qassas/workflow
$SPGroup = $web.SiteGroups["GroupName"]
$SPGroup
```

**Output**

[image]

Where the property `OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership` will be

- **False** if `who can view the membership of the group` is **Everyone**,
- **True** if `who can view the membership of the group` is **Group Members**.

In my case, it's `True` because it's assigned to **Group Members**

[image]